# How to select a date interval in IQueryable<>?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have a `IQueryable<Journey>` that i collect from my entity model. I want to use this to get a new set of `IQueryable<Journey>` but only within a specific date interval from 2 textboxes on my webpage.

A `Journey` has `Journey.DateFrom` and `Journey.DateTo` which are strings ("YYYYMMDD").

I thought i would do something like this:

(journeys is `IQueryable<Journey>`)

```
if (tb_DateFrom.Text != ""){
    journeys = from j in journeys
               where Convert.ToInt32(j.DateTo) >= Convert.ToInt32(tb_DateFrom.Text)
               select j;
}
if (tb_DateTo.Text != ""){
        journeys = from j in journeys
                   where Convert.ToInt32(j.DateFrom) <= Convert.ToInt32(tb_DateTo.Text)
                   select j;
    }
```

But i get error saying that linq doesnt know how to do `Convert.ToInt32`, neither does it know how to do int.parse or datetime.parse. What works is to use `IEnumerable<Journey>` instead of `IQueryable<Journey>` but that is so slow that the website crash since the data im comparing is quite huge.

How can i work this out, is the only answer to get the format in db to datetime?

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
if (tb_DateFrom.Text != "") {
    journeys = from j in journeys
               where j.DateTo.CompareTo(tb_DateFrom.Text) >= 0
               select j;
}

if (tb_DateTo.Text != "") {
    journeys = from j in journeys
               where j.DateFrom.CompareTo(tb_DateTo.Text) <= 0
               select j;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was easier than everyone though :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you convert textbox values to datetime and then compare the dates in the where clause, instead of converting to int

```
 DateTime? dateFrom = null, dateTo = null;

 if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_DateFrom.Text))
    dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(tb_DateFrom.Text, "yyyyMMdd", null);

 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_DateTo.Text))
    dateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(tb_DateTo.Text, "yyyyMMdd", null);

 if (dateFrom.HasValue)
    journeys = journeys.Where(j => j.DateFrom >= dateFrom.Value);

 if (dateTo.HasValue)
    journeys = journeys.Where(j => j.DateTo <= dateTo.Value);
```

Comment: because i cant compare string with datetime.

`Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'`

j.DateFrom/To are strings and dateFrom/To are datetimes.

Comment: Oh sorry I completely misunderstood your problem

Answer (score 0):

As the string format you have sorts in the same order as the dates they represent, I don't see why you have to convert their data format at all. Just do (untested):

```
journeys = from j in journeys
               where j.DateTo >= tb_DateFrom.Text && j.DateFrom >= tb_DateTo.Text
               select j;
```

Update, after Joakim's comment, still just using the sort order of the strings:

```
journeys = from j in journeys
           where j.DateTo.CompareTo(tb_DateFrom.Text) >= 0 && 
                 j.DateFrom.CompareTo(tb_DateTo.Text) <= 0
           select j;
```

(Det borde väl fungera, Joakim?)

Oops, I missed the accepted answer, but I'll still leave my first edit...

Comment: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: @Joakim Börjesson: Parse them, like so; "where j.DateTo >= DateTime.Parse(tb_DateFrom.Text) ... "

Comment: @C.McAtackney: You realize I have j.DateTo as String? It is a string in the db. So first of all linq doesnt support datetime.parse, i would have to parse the textbox before the query. Second you cant compare string >= datetime.

`Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: Date as string in DB, thats bad

Answer (score 0):

```
private DateTime getDate(string yyyyMmDd, DateTime defaultValue)
{
  DateTime ret  = DateTime.MinValue;
  if (!DateTime.TryParse(yyyyMmDd, out ret)) 
     return defaultValue;

  return ret;
}

var to = DateTime.Parse(tb_DateTo.Text);
var from  = DateTime.Parse(tb_DateFrom.Text);
journeys.Where(j=> getDate(j.DateFrom, DateTime.MaxValue) <= from && getDate(j.DateTo, DateTime.MinValue) >= to);
```

Comment: Nice try Jason i had that in mind aswell. Tho, i get an error when the linq querry is run. System.NotSupportedException, Linq doesn't recognize the method getDate.

Comment: so you are using LinqToEntities and not LinqToSql? You may need to iterate the enumeration and manually check, or update the database to something a little saner